# moveRowAtIndexPath – animation of dropping the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

As I enter the canMoveRowAtIndexPath mode, everything is beautifully animated (other cells sliding as I drag the cell above them) until I drop the cell to a desired location. It just pops in in no time. How can I animate it (as it's for example in Reminders app)?

**PROBLEM SOLVED by maddy's comment.**

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` (or any of the other `reload` methods from your `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`? If you are, don't. The table will already be up to date. You just need to update your data structures in this method.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was unnecessary – I just forgot to uncomment it, but didn't realise it may have any impact on this. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this Link](https://github.com/beefon/TableView-Extended-Animations) might be help full for you.

UITableViewExtendedAnimations category allows to perform new animations,
such as moving cells, exchanging cells, and making transitions from one
cell to another.
There are three new methods on UITableView:

```
-moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
-transitRowAtIndexPath:toRowIndexPath:
-exchangeRowAtIndexPath:withRowAtIndexPath:
```

This was done using a regular Objective-C category.

To perform such animations UITableViewDelegate protocol was extended.
There are a couple of new methods you have to implement to make these
animations possible. Take a look at example project to see that methods.

Video of the sample project:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/bC-YTq9C0Sk